# Google Play services missing or without correct permission

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services

currently I am doing the user registration class by using Firebase authentication. However, the logcat showed this error. May I know how to solve this? I have install google play services in SDK tools and added   in manifest file. Thank you:)

error1: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so"

error2: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.

Error3: tid 3325: eglSurfaceAttrib(1354): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

Editted: those problem arised due to the emulator, but as long as you installed google play service on the emulator, the problem will solve

Answer (score -1):

Try running it on a real device, emulator tends to cause errors.